# Move multiple files with various extensions by batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, wildcard

I intend to move wildcard filenames with various types to one folder

I tried the followings, but neither of them work

move D:\Users\name\Desktop*.pptx,*.xls,*.pdf D:\Users\name\Desktop\documents

move D:\Users\name\Desktop*.{pptx,xls,pdf} D:\Users\name\Desktop\documents

move D:\Users\name\Desktop*.pptx *.xls *.pdf D:\Users\name\Desktop\documents

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`move` does not support multiple wildcards at once. You could either:

- call `move` three times, once for each extension:

```
  move D:\Users\name\Desktop\*.pptx D:\Users\name\Desktop\documents
  move D:\Users\name\Desktop\*.xls  D:\Users\name\Desktop\documents
  move D:\Users\name\Desktop\*.pdf  D:\Users\name\Desktop\documents
```

- or, to keep it all on one line:

```
  for %X in (pptx xls pdf) do @move D:\users\name\desktop\*.%X D:\users\name\desktop\documents
```

---

[ *EDIT* ]  As pointed out in @Squashman's comment, the above is the correct syntax to use at the command line. When `for` is used in a batch file, instead, the `%` in `%X` variable names must be doubled, like `for %%X in ...`.

Comment: Since the O/P tagged this question with `batch-file` you may want to change your `FOR` code to use required syntax for the variable when being used in a `batch-file`.

Comment: It works perfectly after adding one more % to %X. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have one more option with `ROBOCOPY`.  You can use the `/MOV` option to have the files deleted after they are copied.  One benefit is that `ROBOCOPY` will accept multiple wildcards.

```
robocopy "D:\Users\name\Desktop" "D:\Users\name\Desktop\documents" *.pptx *.pdf /MOV
```

Answer (score -1):

Commas are fine, but you need to supply the full path to the target either by path variable or explicitly.